# LINQ: failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use sum in code below but I get the error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

```
Product_Order:
    ---------------- ----------- ---------
    |   ProductId   | OrderId   | Quantity |
    ---------------- ----------- ---------
```

I get the error at "`let quantity`"

```
  var fullInfo = (from product in allProdcts
                 let quantity = db.Product_Order.Where(x=> x.ProductId == product.ID).Sum(x => x.Quantity)
                select new ReportVm
                    {                          
                        ProductId = product.ID,
                        ProductName = product.Name,
                        AmountProduct = quantity,
                        TotPrice = (quantity)*(product.Price)
                    }).ToList();
```

This is my `Product_Order` table(M-M relation):

```
Product_Order:
    ---------------- ----------- ---------
    |   ProductId   | OrderId   | Quantity |
    ---------------- ----------- ---------
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please add the auto-generated POCO class of `Product_Order` to your question. It is important how the `Quantity` property is defined (`int` or `int?`),

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki As I understand it correctly, the code will give me value 0 if null?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I get the same error by using that code. But just adding `(int?)` without `??` worked without any error(but I still need value 0 if null). EDIT: `??` won't work with this code, I tried it before I asked this question. But it works outside of that code. Any other solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need allow a nullable `Quantity`, You can achieve it using `??` expression and cast to `int?` when you use `Sum()`.

```
.Sum(x => (int?)x.Quantity)??0
```

Your query should look like

```
var fullInfo = (from product in allProdcts
            let quantity = db.Product_Order.Where(x => x.ProductId == product.ID).Sum(x => (int?)x.Quantity)??0
            select new ReportVm
            {
                ProductId = product.ID,
                ProductName = product.Name,
                AmountProduct = quantity,
                TotPrice = (quantity)*(product.Price)
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: If `Quantity` is `int`, casting it to an `int?` won't change anthing and if it is of type `int?` you don't need to cast it.

Comment: Not true @Sefe - I just tried similar with a `decimal`  and if I didn't cast to a `decimal?` the error occurred - it's taking the `Sum` of `null` and doesn't have the logic to know what it's going to pass that resulting `null` into.

Answer (score 1):

You may not use an aggregate function returning a non nullable type on an empty collection. In your case, Sum() fails when the where clause on db.Product_Order returns no elements. Following Solution, defining 0 as the default value, should work:

```
var fullInfo = (from product in allProdcts
                let productOrder = db.Product_Order.Where(x => x.ProductId == product.ID)
                let quantity = productOrder.Any() ? productOrder.Sum(x => x.Quantity) : 0
                select new ReportVm
                {
                    ProductId = product.ID,
                    ProductName = product.Name,
                    AmountProduct = quantity,
                    TotPrice = (quantity) * (product.Price)
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution...

```
let quantity = db.Product_Order.Where(x=> x.ProductId == product.ID).Sum(x => x.Quantity == null ? 0 : x.Quantity)
```